# What would 3PC do in such a scenario?

Tags: distributed-transactions

We are using 3PC (three-phase commitment) for a distributed transaction. There are 4 nodes, A, B, C, D, where A is the coordinator.

1. A received OK from all others and sent the prepare-to-commit message to them.
2. While C and D received this message and moved to prepared state, B crashes and doesn't received this message (thus remaining in the wait state).
3. A timeouts on B and sends abort to all others, but only D receives the abort message, while C crashes before receiving the abort message.

Now the question is: What will C do after recovery? According to http://courses.cs.vt.edu/~cs5204/fall00/distributedDBMS/sreenu/3pc.html, C will commit upon recovery following the failure transition instead of aborting as D does. Won't that result in an inconsistent state? Or C has some mechanism to detect that the transaction in an aborted state?

Answer (score 0):

I think there's a wrong assumption in your question about the behaviour of the B node? If B crashes before it moves to prepared state then it resides in waiting for state after the restart and will be aborted.

I expect that C node will be aborted as it will be commanded by the coordinator to do so. I think this will be similar to 2PC. It's up to coordinator to periodically check if the lost nodes are available again. When C is restarted the coordinator can see it and push the node to be rolled-back as abort message will be resent.

Comment: Sorry there is a typo. I've changed B into C in the last paragraph. Not sure if the coordinator will keep checking C and resend message after it recovers.

Comment: I see your point and I was not sure how to put it differently. Now I found an article https://www.researchgate.net/publication/275154978_Three-Phase_Commit. I would cite from there: "Notice that a recovering participant cannot commit a transaction even if the participant is in a pre-commit state with respect to the transaction. This is because the operation-all sites might have decided to abort the transaction after the participant had failed if none of them was in a pre-commit state. In this case, the participant must ask the other sites about the final status of the transaction."

Comment: This point fact is that C is recovering. The C can find the state by waiting for the coordinator to be commanded. Or it can ask the other participant to understand the final state. This is up to the implementation.

Comment: Seems that 3PC does not support all kinds of multipoint failures... as discussed in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21424962/how-does-three-phase-commit-avoid-blocking.

Comment: From my point of view you are right. The 3PC itself (as a protocol) is not capable to resolve that situation. But the implementation of 3PC should count with the state and being able to finish the transaction correctly.